# SQL Query to find greatest value among all in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g

I am new to sql queries and executing the query:

I have looked up some examples online but did not succeed much.

Here is the query

```
SELECT m.genre, m.movie_title, m.release_year, m.movie_length 
FROM MOVIE m GROUP BY m.genre, m.movie_title, m.release_year,m.movie_length 
ORDER BY m.movie_length asc;
```

If someone can explain on how I can get the values , would highly appreciate the help.

Thank you

Comment: Your question has already been answered, but next time, please, choose only one RDBMS tag, not two (`mysql` and `oracle11g`). These are different RDBMS engines with differences in SQL syntax. If you need solution for both, then clarify your question with reasons for such a need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the greatest length of all movies for a given genre, you can use the MAX() aggregate function. All you will have to do is group by the genre. This is a little tricky, because you can't just jump in and select the movie title, or it won't group correctly. Start by getting the genre and max movie length for it:

```
SELECT m.genre, MAX(m.movie_length) AS longestMovie
FROM movie m
GROUP BY m.genre;
```

Once you've done that, you can join it with your table and get the max movies:

```
SELECT m.genre, m.movie_title, m.release_year, m.movie_length
FROM movie m
JOIN (SELECT m.genre, MAX(m.movie_length) AS longestMovie
      FROM movie m
      GROUP BY m.genre) t
ON t.genre = m.genre AND t.longestMovie = m.movie_length;
```

Here is a working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d6b70/1).

Comment: That does help but It does not select all the genres with greatest movie length. Any idea on how i can achieve that?

Comment: @Mani I misunderstood your question originally, please see edit.

Comment: Thank you, this makes so much sence. I did not know we could do a join in the same table itself. Thanks

Comment: @Mani no problem. That's a tricky problem if you've never seen anything like it before.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT m.genre, m.movie_title, m.release_year, m.movie_length 
FROM MOVIE as m order by m.movie_length desc limit 0,1;
```

After adding order by DESC put the limit to get only 1 record. 0 means to start at 0 index and 1 to define the number of records.

Comment: I am not sure how this will achieve getting the highest movie length among each genre. I tried executing the query but it does not execute. If you could explain a little.

Comment: I am sorry, i forget to add column for orderby. Please try again the updated query.

Comment: FROM MOVIE <AS> m. He missed that out as well as ORDER BY <m.movie_length>.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.genre, m.movie_title, m.release_year, m.movie_length
FROM MOVIE AS m ORDER BY m.movie_length DESC LIMIT 1;
```

This should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the query still doesnot execute and also I dont get the statement after "AS".

Comment: What is the error? Please CTRL + C. AS simply means that instead of typing something like MOVIE.genre, you gave it another nickname call m so you can do something like m.genre. It is usually used to shorten the statement and to also minimize the chances of a typo.

Comment: I would just like to jump in and say that the AS here is optional. @Mani, it is doing the same thing as you are when you say `FROM movie m` in your query in the question.

Comment: The error is :
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

if I do 
select m.genre from MOVIE m <-- this results me in all the genres 

Where as
select m.genre from MOVIE as m <-- this results me in error.

Comment: I am not sure if my question is making sense. I want to select greatest length among all movies of that genre.

Comment: I understand but this should not be the case. Try and echo the sql statement and see what it writes and CTRL+C here.